# PhoneGap iPad lauch screen does not fit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, launch, cordova

I created an App which is compatible to iPhone and iPad. Because it is based on HTML (PhoneGap) the App itself is the same for both devices (HTML scales well!). **But the launch screen image does not fill out the display on the iPad upon launch.**

In my Resorces folder there is only the iPhone launch image which is to small for the iPad, how can I add an other one for the iPad?

Comment: Found this one on the inet http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/6/29/updating-for-the-iphone-4-retinal-display.html

Comment: and this http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the launch image file (`UILaunchImageFile`) property in your application's info.plist:

For example, if you set the value for the key `UILaunchImageFile~ipad` to `iPad`, your file names should be `iPad-Portrait.png` and `iPad-Landscape.png`. You could similarly change it for the iPhone, or use the default (`Default.png`) for iPhone.

This is defined in [Information Property List Files](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW9).

Comment: Thanks! I will check this! There are some different offical Apple documentations out there...

Comment: iOS prior to 3.2 does not support this. Check my answer below if you're building against an older iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I've found a solution to this issue, using phonegap 1.9 dropping this code into your apps delegate should do the trick:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default-Portrait" ofType:@"png"]];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [image release];

    imageView.tag = 1;
    [window addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

That needs to go in the 'applicationDidFinishLaunching' function after the [ super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application ] call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the launch image as mentioned above, but also check to make sure that after the build your launch icons are in the right place. After doing a Build/Run of a PhoneGap project, check the Resources folder in xcode. I found that my additional launch screens and app icons hadn't been moved there in build. Once I copied them in manually and re-built, all the icons and launch screens worked as they should for ipad and iphone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried a whole bunch of solutions, which were proposed here and on the net. Nothing worked. My Problem was that I'm using a deployment target < iOS 3.2 which does not support the Info.plist settings **Mo.** described in his post.

Unfortunately Apple has several documentations on the Info.plist / splash screen matter. This one helped:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18

You set up your project like this:
Make no *"Launch image"* settings in Info.plist. Just add the following images:

`Default.png` **--> This is the (big) iPad splash image**

`Default-Landscape.png` --> This is the (big landscape) iPad splash image

`Default-Portrait.png` --> This is the (big portrait) iPad splash image

`Default~iphone.png` --> This is the (small) iPhone splash image

To support high-resolution displays:

`Default@2x~iphone.png` --> --> This is the (retina) iPhone splash image

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a file called "Default.png" in your resources - splash folder. This will remove it, yes i know it sounds silly, because it's an IPAD app, but if you don't want to touch the C code, just add or replace that file. It get's called even if it's an IPAD (meaning, actually default.png is for iphone, but ...well whatever, just try it!)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the documentation regarding adding the UILaunchImageFile key to the .plist file http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html .

This works but you have to remember to drag and drop your ipad image into XCode. It will not work by simply adding the file in the file browser, you must use Xcode!